# Why does Joda Time report a wrong offset for a timezone, while the Android Java Api returns the correct one?

Tags: java, android, jodatime

I included Joda Time into my Android project to be able to use updated timezone information.

Unfortunately, I got a report from a user in Bangladesh that the timezone offset is calculated incorrectly.

Testing it on the emulator, I too am getting incorrect offsets.  After running an Android emulator using the flag `-timezone Asia/Dhaka` I see this in my app:

Reported TimeZone offset using normal Java API

```
TimeZone zone = TimeZone.getDefault();
String zoneName = zone.getDisplayName(daylight, TimeZone.SHORT);
int millisOffset = zone.getOffset(System.currentTimeMillis());
=> Asia/Dhaka, Offset +6 hours
```

Reported using the Joda Time Library

```
DateTime today = new DateTime();
String name = today.getZone();
int millisOffset = today.getZone().getOffset(today.getMillis());
=> Asia/Dhaka, Offset +7 hours
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: What version of Joda are you using?

Comment: @MattBall 2.3.3, as far as I can tell. I also updated the tzdata about a week ago.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. [This snippet](https://gist.github.com/mjball/e634b1ab1956c1c87bda) prints `21600000`, which is 6 hours and therefore correct.

Comment: Though I ran that snippet on a desktop computer, not an Android device.

Comment: Something is definitely strange. Although the Android clock on the emulator shows the right time of 2:26am, (and I assume it uses the Java API), doing `(new DateTime()).toString()` gives me an incorrect  time and offset => `2014-10-30T03:26:42.885+07:00`

Comment: Perhaps Joda does not respect whatever you're doing to set the default time zone. What does `DateTimeZone.getDefault()` return?

Comment: I get `Asia/Dhaka`. I just tried the same thing with Asia/Kolkata, Africa/Cairo, and they both seem to work fine. Not sure why Dhaka seems to be having the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a known issue in JodaTime, specific to Dhaka.

It is apparently fixed in the latest version of Joda-Time

https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/issues/208

Answer (score 0):

In order for Joda to give the correct offset, you must provide a datetime instant.Without a datetime instant, it is impossible to calculate the offset since we have different offsets(daylight savings). This is how I would use Joda to get offset in  + HH:mm format :

```
    int offsetInMillis = DateTimeZone.forID(zoneId).getOffset(new DateTime().getMillis());
    String offset = String.format("%02d:%02d", Math.abs(offsetInMillis / 3600000),
            Math.abs((offsetInMillis / 60000) % 60));
    offset = (offsetInMillis >= 0 ? "+" : "-") + offset;
```